# In the hypothetical setence, can "was" be used?

Tags: tense

> However, if you tried to copy the original rather than your imaginary drawing, you might find your drawing now **was** a little better.

How come it is possible to use was instead of **be** or **is**? Because my knowledge tells me that the main clause of hypothetical sentence should have the form of *would + root verb*.

Answer (score 2):

The use of the imperfect (*was*) in this type of construction often appears in common speech. You are correct that it should be the conditional *would + verb*, i.e. *would be*.